# 2D array of structures in posix shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I have a structure for hash-table

```
struct node
{
    char *key;
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

#define TABLESIZE 100

unsigned int hash(const char *str, int tablesize)
{

    return std::hash<std::string>{}(str) % tablesize;
}
```

Creating 4 child process by fork().

And im need declaring 2d array of this structure in posix shared memory for access in this array from all child process.

How to do it?

It is work when i create 2d array with malloc:

```
node **table = (node **) malloc(1024*1024);
```

this is functions for lookup and set data ;

```
int lookup(node **table, const char *key)
{
    unsigned index = hash(key, TABLESIZE);
    const node *it = table[index];
    while(it != NULL && strcmp(it->data, key) != 0)
    {
        it = it->next;
    }
    return it != NULL;
}

int set(node **table, const char *key,const char *data)
{
    if( !lookup(table, key) )
    {
        unsigned index = hash(key, TABLESIZE);
        node *new_node= (node *)malloc(sizeof *new_node);

        if(new_node == NULL)
            return 0;
        new_node->key = (char *) malloc(strlen(key)+1);
        new_node->data = (char *)malloc(strlen(data)+1);

        strcpy(new_node->key, key);
        strcpy(new_node->data, data);
        new_node->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_node;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but when i try do this by mmap my programm cracks and child process becomes a zombie

Sorry for my bad english